# How can I know the method that HMM use to choose the hidden states automatically?

Tags: markov-hidden-model

As I know, I can just decide the number of hidden states, then put my observations fit into my HMM model, the model will generate the hidden states for me.
I am really curious how it does work. Can anyone explain the calculation or share the link which has such details with me.

Comment: What do you mean with: "I can just decide the number of hidden states [...] the model will generate the hidden states for me?"

Comment: `>>> remodel = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3, covariance_type="full", n_iter=100)
>>> remodel.fit(X)
GaussianHMM(algorithm='viterbi', ...
>>> Z2 = remodel.predict(X)`      
Here is the sample I found from [link](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).
I also worked with some sample data and they works well. As I know, number of  **n_components** means number of **hidden states**.   After called **fit(X)**, the **transmat_** is generated automatically, so I want to how it does work... 
Thanks!